# Bug: fillbetween with multiple plots

Tags: pgfplots

Using the pgfplots package `fillbetween` in two `tikzpicture` with the same `name path` gives different results.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{poly}{0}{\pgfmathparse{-x^3+5*(x^2)-3*x-3}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xtick       = {-1.2,2,4.2},
    xticklabels = {$a$,$\zeta$,$b$},
    ytick       = {3},
    yticklabels = {$f(\zeta)$},
    samples     = 160,
    domain      = -1.2:4.2,
    xmin = -2, xmax = 5,
    ymin = -5, ymax = 10,
  ]
  \addplot[name path=poly, black, thick, mark=none, ] {poly};
  \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=1pt] {3};
  \addplot fill between[ 
    of = poly and line, 
    split, % calculate segments
    every even segment/.style = {orange!70},
    every odd segment/.style  = {gray!60}
  ];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xtick       = {-1.2,2,4.2},
    xticklabels = {$a$,$\zeta$,$b$},
    ytick       = {3},
    yticklabels = {$f(\zeta)$},
    samples     = 160,
    domain      = -1.2:4.2,
    xmin = -2, xmax = 5,
    ymin = -5, ymax = 10,
  ]
  \addplot[name path=poly, black, thick, mark=none, ] {poly};
  \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=1pt] {3};
  \addplot fill between[ 
    of = poly and line, 
    split, % calculate segments
    every even segment/.style = {orange!70},
    every odd segment/.style  = {gray!60}
  ];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a workaround? I cannot use different `name path` since the plots are generated by a script.

Comment: Your MWE works fine here. `pgfplots` 1.12.1, recently updated TeX Live 2015.

Comment: I am using Windows, pdflatex and have pgfplots 1.12.1 installed. No effect if I set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}`.

Comment: Update TikZ to v.3.0 too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in another ticket: http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/79/

The answer from Christian Feuersänger:

> Thanks for the detailed output! Your listing indicates that your
>   system has PGF 2.10 (the previous stable of PGF). In this
>   constellation, I can reproduce the problem.
>
> A root cause analysis
>   reveals that pgfplots successfully detects that it has an outdated
>   PGF, but it fails to apply automatic patches for this release. This is
>   a bug in pgfplots and I will take care of it. A solution is to upgrade
>   to PGF 3.0.0 (or newer).

And the workaround:

```
% PATCH TO FIX INCOMPATIBILITY BETWEEN PGFPLOTS 1.12 AND PGF 2.10
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@intersect@addto@path@names#1#2{%
\edef\tikz@marshal{#2\expandafter\noexpand\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@#1\endcsname}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tikz@marshal%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\tikz@marshal\expandafter{\tikz@intersect@temppath}}%
\expandafter\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\tikz@intersect@namedpaths\expandafter{\tikz@marshal}%
}
\pgfkeys{%
/tikz/name path global/.code={%
\expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@#1\endcsname=\relax
\tikz@key@name@path@new{#1}{\gdef}%
},
/tikz/name path local/.code={%
\pgfkeys{/tikz/name path={#1}}%
},
/tikz/name path/.code={%
\tikz@key@name@path@new{#1}{\def}%
},
}
\makeatother
```